# String methods with higher-order functions

Tags: javascript

I ran into a weird thing while trying to use String methods with higher-order functions. This will throw an error:

```
['a', 'b'].some('boo'.includes)
```

I have to wrap the predicate in another function to make it work. But isn't `'boo'.includes` already a function?

This works with plain functions:

```
const boo = {
    includes: () => true
};

['a', 'b'].some(boo.includes)
```

Is there some special property of String methods that prevents them from being composed like this?

Comment: `.includes` is a function, but it requires an argument in order to work. And `.some()` won't work unless you pass it a function that returns a Boolean. Of course it won't work if you just pass it by itself. That's like saying `"Test".replace()`.

Comment: `some` takes as it's first argument a function that takes one parameter, correct? Here I am passing it a function that takes one parameter and returns a boolean. I don't quite understand why that's not working

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's completely incorrect and not related to the problem. Both my answer and ASDFGerte's explain the actual problem.

Comment: @JosephSible I don't think you understood my comment. The solution requires that an argument be passed to `.includes()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's `some`'s job to pass that argument. You're supposed to pass a function to it, not the result of calling one.

Comment: @JosephSible I fully understand passing functions. You are not following my point.

Comment: What I find odd is that Scott got 3 upvotes, without any correction while being wrong. It had me quite confused for a while.

Comment: Scott, `boo.includes` IS a function which returns a boolean. What I think you are describing is called "Currying" and while it is necessary in this case, it is not required in the functional paradigm.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Slight correction, it’s partial application, not currying. The two are often confused but distinct.

Comment: It's a curried, fully applied function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`"boo".includes` is nothing else than `String.prototype.includes`. Calling it on the string "boo" however sets `this` to "boo", which gives the proper context to the function. E.g. `"boo".includes("b")` is the same as `String.prototype.includes.call("boo", "b")`.

Passing it as an argument, e.g. `['a', 'b'].some('boo'.includes)`, is the same as `['a', 'b'].some(String.prototype.includes)`, which then lacks the proper `this` as context.

You can of course use e.g. `bind`: `['a', 'b'].some(String.prototype.includes.bind("boo"))`, or use the optional second parameter thisArg for `some`: `['a', 'b'].some(String.prototype.includes, "boo")`. This will get rid of the error. However, you will then notice, that `some` passes not only the element, but the index as second parameter, and the array itself as third. This is a problem, as `includes` also takes an optional second parameter for the start position. This causes likely unwanted behavior, as e.g. the array element "b" is at index 1, and `"boo".includes("b", 1) === false`.

All in all, you need a function which is so different to `String.prototype.includes`, that it's just easier to wrap it in a new function that actually does what you want:
`['a', 'b'].some(e => "boo".includes(e))`, as you already noticed.

Comment: Thank you, this was really informative and I appreciate the clarity in explaining how the context is lost.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Marcus's comment is incorrect. It's completely normal in functional programming to pass around functions without their required arguments. Here's the actual problem:

The callback you pass to `some` is called with three arguments: `currentValue`, `index`, and `array`, and its `this` is set to `undefined` unless you pass a second parameter to `some`. The method `String.prototype.includes` takes two arguments: `search` and `start`, and its `this` is used as the string to be searched. As a result of this interaction, `includes` gets called without a string to search, so it gives an error.

Even if you fix the above via `bind` or by passing a second parameter to `some`, this won't entirely fix the problem though. The other half of the problem is the second argument. `some` considers it to be `index` but `includes` considers it to be `start`. As a result, the `b` won't be searched for until the second character of the string, so even though the error will be gone, the test will still return false.

In this case, a wrapper function is unavoidable to get the desired behavior.