# Javascript: Pass include method to filter array

Tags: javascript, arrays, built-in

Filtering arrays in Javascript is possible by passing a custom function to the `filter` method:

```
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(item => item < 5);
```

It's also possible to pass the function as a "reference":

```
function largerThanFive(item) {
  return item => item < 5;
}

const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(largerThanFive);
```

I tried to use this to intersect two arrays via:

```
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const smallArray = [0, 1, 2];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(smallArray.includes);
```

But I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I don't understand why. Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: The main problem, as Nina's answer shows, is that functions are not (only) object methods.  When you pass a reference to an object's method, unless the function is bound to that object (via `bind` or arrow function binding, or however), you've lost the reference to `this`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String methods with higher-order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737301/string-methods-with-higher-order-functions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using a prototype function, you are loosing the reference to the object `smallArray`. In this case you need either to bind the object with [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),

```js
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const smallArray = [0, 1, 2];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(Array.prototype.includes.bind(smallArray));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

or use `thisArg` parameter of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const smallArray = [2, 1, 0];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(Array.prototype.includes, smallArray);

console.log(filteredArray); // 2 is missing
```

**But both above approaches do not work**, because [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses a second parameter `fromIndex`, which is handed over from the calling function as `index` and omits values to be checked whoes indices are smaller.

As result, you need a function which supports the same function signature as the api of the methods supplies or which is smaller as the callback is using.

For example a working approach would be to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as `thisArg` along with [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) as callback. This method uses only one parameter, which fits perfectly.

```js
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const smallArray = [2, 1, 0];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(smallArray));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Or of course just pass a lambda: `bigArray .filter (x => smallArray .includes (x))`.

Comment: I'm just now learning that `.filter` takes a `this` argument as it's second argument. Thanks for that, very helpful

Comment: This omits the second problem explained in the dupe target - `filter` passes the current index as second argument, and `includes` takes an optional second parameter `fromIndex`.

Comment: Nina, thank you for your answer. I would agree with @ASDFGerte here- there is another bug that isn't addressed by your answer. 

I also note that it would be more informative if you could explain what "the object" means when you say "you are losing the reference to the object".

Comment: @BashuNaimi-Roy, please see edit.

Comment: It's much better Nina, thank you for the time you took.

Answer (score 3):

The error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` is caused when you call a function that expects an Object as its argument, but pass undefined or null instead

You can get each item inside filter, then you can check whether the `smallArray` has that item like,

```
smallArray.includes(item);
```

Snippet as follows:

```js
const bigArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const smallArray = [0, 1, 2];
const filteredArray = bigArray.filter(item => {
  return smallArray.includes(item);
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: This is absolutely true but doesn't answer the question: 


```But I get the error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

I don't understand why. Can someone elaborate on that?```

Comment: @BashuNaimi-Roy, Updated the reason for the cause of the error..

Comment: Thank you for the update. Could you also clarify which function expects the Object as its argument and why it's receiving undefined/null in this case?