# Passing an array.push function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem passing an array.push function in javascript having a code like this:

```js
const array = [];
    addToArray("works", (e) => array.push(e));
    addToArray("notWorks", array.push);
    doConsoleLog("hello", console.log);
    
    function addToArray(element, pushFn) {
      pushFn(element);
    }
    
    function doConsoleLog(message, log) {
      log(message);
    }
```

Just curious how's that first call of addToArray works, but second causes `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. How is it possible? Type of array.push is a function. It is not possible to pass functions directly like in the case of console.log above, which works pretty well?

Comment: very related: [string-methods-with-higher-order-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737301/string-methods-with-higher-order-functions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` is a method of `array`. When invoked, it uses [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) as a reference to the object it is being called on. If you pass it around like a normal function, you will lose that reference, the method will use the value of `this` defined at the moment of the call (inside `addToArray`, `this` is probably `document.window`), and will therefore fail.

In order to pass around a method, you need to bind it to the object you want it to operate on, in this case `array`. This is true for any object method in JavaScript. [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) exists exactly for this purpose: it "binds" a function (in this case your method) to a given value of `this`, in order to work correctly.

```
const array = [];

addToArray("now it works", array.push.bind(array));
// or
addToArray("now it works", Array.prototype.push.bind(array));

function addToArray(element, pushFn) {
  pushFn(element);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you pass a function like you did in the second case, it executes itself immediately, and **array.push** doesn't really mean something.
A callback function should be executed later on in the outer function.
Unlike the second example, in the first one you don't execute the function immediately, but only when you call it inside the outer function.

Answer (score -2):

Your code have a lot of mistakes. What exactly should do this code? if you want to push new items in array use spread operator

```
const array = [...[], "works", "notWorks"]


const array = [];
        addToArray("works", (e) => array.push(e));
        addToArray("notWorks", array.push);
        doConsoleLog("hello", console.log);

    function addToArray(element, pushFn) {
      pushFn(element); //function must return something
    }

    function doConsoleLog(message, log) {
      log(message);  //function must return something
    }
```